# query with umlauts in where clause returns nothing

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to filter a table with German umlauts in the where condition in my Symfony app, but strangely that doesn't work.

code:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p')
    ->from('AppBundle:Tablename', 'p');
$queryBuilder->andWhere('p.firm like :searchTerm');
$parameters['searchTerm'] = '%'.$data['search'].'%';
$dql = $this->entityManager
    ->createQuery($queryBuilder->getDql())
    ->setParameters($parameters);
```

data:

```
MySQL [mydb_de]> SELECT firm FROM tablename WHERE firm LIKE '%bar%';
+---------+
| firm    |
+---------+
| föo&bar |
+---------+
1 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [mydb_de]> SELECT firm FROM tablename WHERE firm LIKE '%föo%';
+---------+
| firm    |
+---------+
| föo&bar |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I get the expected results when I search for `bar`, but there are no results when I search for `föo`.

additional info from db:

```
MySQL [mydb_de]> SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Table            | Create Table                          |
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
| tablename | CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `firm` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1902 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [mydb_de]> SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'tablename';
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name      | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time          | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| tablename | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 1835 |             94 |      172556 | 281474976710655 |        33792 |         0 |           1902 | 2018-04-16 11:34:57 | 2018-04-16 11:34:57 | 2018-04-16 11:34:57 | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [mydb_de]> show variables like '%character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I tried to switch the charset in my config.yml (`doctrine.dbal.charset`) to `latin1` and to `latin1_swedish_ci` without luck.

I enabled the logging (`doctrine.dbal.logging`), found the query in the Profiler and checked the searchTerm, looks good I guess:

[image: query parameter in Profiler]

We have databases for many countries, some of them use utf8, but others don't. Our german-db do not use utf8 as far as I know and it's not possible to change that in the near future

Symfony-Version: 3.4.6
Doctrine-Version: 2.5.14
MySQL-Version: 5.5.47

Anybody have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: "Our german-db do not use utf8 as far as I know and it's not possible to change that in the near future" German umlauts would require the tables charset atleast utf8 not latin1

Comment: why would you want to set to `latin1_swedish_ci` instead `latin1_german_ci`?

Comment: Possible, it will be helpful - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37739

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration of Symfony for Doctrine is the following:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        url: '(your database url)'
```

This configuration specifies that the database tables should use interclassment `utf8mb4`. Precisely to work with special chars (and also complex utf-8 characters (f.i. emojis) if you don't use mariadb).